# How would I split this expression with regex?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I'm working on solving an equation but I will like to use the constants to program my solution.

The method I'm working on is called decompose which decomposes the equation into constants. The problem is that when I split, an equation with a negative constant will yield an array with the absolute value of the constants. How can I achieve the minus sign while still using regex?

If the input is `ax+by=c`, the output should be `{a,b,c}`.

Helpful bonus: Is there a way to delete the empty elements that is created when I split. For example, if I type equation `2x+3y=6`, I end up with a "raw" array that contains the elements `{2,,3,,6}`

Code:

```
public static int[] decompose(String s)
{
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");

    String[] termRaw = s.split("\\D"); //Splits the equation into constants *and* empty spaces.
    ArrayList<Integer> constants = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Values are placed into here if they are integers.
    for(int k = 0 ; k < termRaw.length ; k++)
    {
        if(!(termRaw[k].equals("")))
        {
            constants.add(Integer.parseInt(termRaw[k]));
        }

    }
    int[] ans = new int[constants.size()];

    for(int k = 0 ; k < constants.size(); k++) //ArrayList to int[]
    {
        ans[k] = constants.get(k);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output given the input `2x+3y=6` ?

Comment: An integer array that has the values `{2,3,6}`. `{a,b,c}` in general.

Comment: What if input is `x+y=5`?

Comment: !!! I forgot about that! Well this program is only for me, so I will be happy to write down `1x+1y=5`. I will, however, gladly accept a solution that takes care of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general strategy to this answer is to split the input equation by operator, then extract out the coefficients in a loop.  However, there are several edge cases which need to be considered:

- a plus symbol (`+`) is prefixed to every minus which does not appear either as the first term
- after splitting, a coefficient of positive one is detected by seeing empty string
- after splitting, a coefficient of negative one is detected by seeing a minus sign

```
String input = "-22x-77y+z=-88-10+33z-q";
input = input.replaceAll(" ", "")             // remove whitespace
             .replaceAll("=-", "-");          // remove equals sign
             .replaceAll("(?<!^)-", "+-");    // replace - with +-, except at start of line
// input = -22x+-77y+z+-88+-10+33z+-

String[] termRaw = bozo.split("[\\+*/=]");
// termRaw contains [-22x, -77y, z, -88, -10, 33z, -]

ArrayList<Integer> constants = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// after splitting,
// termRaw contains [-22, -77, '', -88, -10, 33, '-']
for (int k=0 ; k < termRaw.length ; k++) {
    termRaw[k] = termRaw[k].replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
    if (termRaw[k].equals("")) {
        constants.add(1);
    }
    else if (termRaw[k].equals("-")) {
        constants.add(-1);
    }
    else {
        constants.add(Integer.parseInt(termRaw[k]));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I replace the code with yours, it says that termRaw cannot be resolved. I have tried initializing it, but nothing I know works.

Comment: @IanLimarta I had a typo in there, use `s.split["[\\+\\-*/='")` to split the equation on operators.

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work, but it still prints out absolute values instead of the intended constants (i.e. `-3` as `3`). As you said, the regex removes the operators. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Tim you don't need all those escapes. This is equivalent: `s.split("[-+*/=]")`

Comment: @Bohemian I got compiler errors on the plus and minus without escaping.

Comment: Well, the only way I can get a negative value is if I do `3x+-2y=6` and delete the `\\-` in the regex expression. If it helps, the equation will always be a linear equation.

Comment: @IanLimarta I believe I have it working now, please try again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It works! I do have a question on line 2. Why is it necessary to have the pattern `[^=]`. What would be an example that will break the program if that pattern wasn't in the regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you! I understand now!

Comment: @IanLimarta Last comment: I updated one more time to handle another edge case, but it looks pretty clean at this point.

Comment: @tim did you code it exactly as I did, with the ash then the plus (not the order you had them in originally)?

Comment: Ah yes. I have added it to my program and it works. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `java8`, then you can use this one line method:

```
public static int[] decompose(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ").split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

---

**DEMO:**

*1. Output*

```
[2, 3, 6]
```

*2. Code*

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "2x+3y=6";
        int[] array = decompose(s);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static int[] decompose(String s) {
        return Arrays.stream(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ").split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }
}
```